# Выносные разъемы для USB

Tags: usb, железо

Только не смейтесь, плиз. Сейчас у меня Интернет, в силу сезонных особенностей атмосферы, очень часто отключается: индикатор на модеме Теле2 начинает мигать, и этот модем нужно вытаскивать из компа и снова втыкать. Но в силу непреодолимых причин для меня эта операция невозможна, в обычном виде. Зато это было бы возможно, если бы к компу в разъем USB был воткнут провод, второй конец которого лежал бы на полу. И к этому второму концу был бы подключен разъем, в который можно вставлять USB. Скажите, пожалуйста, такое вообще продается или нет? Задолбало страшно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял, то тебе просто нужен usb удленнитель. 
но то, что все на столько просто меня пугает.
может перефразируй или добавь деталей

Comment: Я понял так же :)

Comment: Проблемы с координацией

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, тебе подойдёт любой [usb-удлинитель](https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--kompiuternye-kabeli-razemy-perekhodniki/55294/list?text=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20usb&glfilter=6179100%3A14945028%2C14945512&local-offers-first=0), продающийся в любом ближайшем магазине, включая магазины, занимающиеся перепродажей китайских товаров. Только определись, тебе нужен удлинитель для usb2 или для usb3.

Comment: Хм, а как это определить?

Comment: Контакты пересчитай. У usb2 один ряд, а у usb3 ещё за ним второй. Разъёмы usb3 обычно синие. И вообще у компа написано должно быть, если в диспетчер устройств зайдёшь.

Comment: Диспетчер устройств - это первое, что пришло в голову. Но там вот что: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGjdo.png <!-- https://postimg.cc/rKQTP3tL -->. Это что, там один 2.0?

Comment: @mathem, возможно. Я бы предпочёл ориентироваться на разъём.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101290/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-mathem).

Comment: Так, а собственно, я не вижу продолжения обсуждения. Как купим - по результату галочки где надо поставлю. А пока всем спасибо.